# Query is extremely slow after ALTER and deploying of updates

Tags: mysql

I run a test server and a production server..

When I do some changes on the db structure on the test server I save all the SQL queries to later run them on the production server when I deploy the updates

Today I deployed some updates on the production server, but at least one query is now so slow that it will timeout (it takes several minutes).. It used to take 1-2 sec

On the test server the same query still runs smooth as it used to

## query

```
SELECT dv.id,dv.client_id,b.name block_name,dv.is_ocr_pending,dv.time,dv.label,dv.is_pdf_broken,dv.is_pdf_scan,dv.is_pic,dv.file_sha1,dv.file_ext,dv.file_ext_thumb,dv.file_size,dv.file_size_original,dv.num_pages,dv.dpi,dv.ocr_confidence,dv.ocr_recall_id,dv.ocr_vatno,cv.name ocr_vatno_name,dv.ocr_vatno_country,dv.ocr_is_vatno_verified,dv.ocr_invoice_id_,dv.ocr_invoice_time,dv.ocr_invoice_time_due,dv.ocr_fi_type,dv.ocr_fi_payment_id_,dv.ocr_is_fi_payment_verified,dv.ocr_fi_creditorno,dv.ocr_bank_code,dv.ocr_bank_code_id,dv.ocr_is_bank_code_verified,dv.ocr_bank_account,dv.ocr_is_bank_account_verified,dv.ocr_bank_iban,dv.ocr_is_bank_iban_verified,dv.ocr_bank_swift,dv.ocr_bank_swift_id,dv.ocr_is_bank_swift_verified,dv.ocr_products_pattern,dv.ocr_total,dv.ocr_is_total_verified,dv.ocr_vat,dv.ocr_currency
FROM `data_voucher` dv
LEFT JOIN `block` b ON b.id=dv.block_id
LEFT JOIN `cache_vatno` cv ON cv.vatno=dv.ocr_vatno
ORDER BY dv.time DESC,dv.id DESC
LIMIT 0,25
```

It doesn't make sense that it timeout on one server but doesn't on the other.. When I dump the table structures the query affect the dumps are exactly the same?

If I exclude the line with `LEFT JOIN cache_vatno cv ON cv.vatno=dv.ocr_vatno` and remove the field `cv.name ocr_vatno_name` from the select clause it runs and completes as it did before the deploy

I don't know what to do?

I have now used perconas extrabackup to dump the production database and deploy it on the test server.. Now the test server has the same issues?

I can browse the table `cache_vatno` in phpmyadmin without problems

The table `data_voucher` has over 100k rows

Have tried to restart mysql

Addeing `EXPLAIN` to the query give this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 times as slow?  And if you ran it again, it would be back to normal?

That is normal.  Before the big `ALTER`, all the data for that query was cached in RAM.  Then the `ALTER` bumped most of it out.  After that, the query had to go to disk, hence 10x slower.  Running again should see it in cache and be fast again.

If this does not fit with what you are seeing, please provide the following so we can dig deeper:

- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table
- The size of each table
- The query
- Value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`
- The ALTER
- Are the JOINs 1:1?  If so, there is a probably a *significant* rewrite to speed it up, even the 1-2 seconds.

Notice that the query must read all of the rows from all 3 tables, and put all the data into a temp table for sorting.

You don't seem to need `LEFT`, can you remove it?

Possible indexes (pending seeing the above info):

```
block -- already has PRIMARY KEY(id)?
cache_vatno:  INDEX(vatno)
data_voucher:  INDEX(time, id)
```

If the joins are 1:1?  Assuming they are, give this rewrite a try:

```
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS dv.id,dv.client_id,
        ( SELECT b.name FROM block b WHERE b.id=dv.block_id ) AS block_name,
        dv.is_ocr_pending,dv.time,dv.label,dv.is_pdf_broken,dv.is_pdf_scan,
        dv.is_pic,dv.file_sha1,dv.file_ext,dv.file_ext_thumb,
        dv.file_size,dv.file_size_original,dv.num_pages,dv.dpi,
        dv.ocr_confidence,dv.ocr_recall_id,dv.ocr_vatno,
        ( SELECT cv.name FROM `cache_vatno` cv
              WHERE cv.vatno=dv.ocr_vatno ) AS ocr_vatno_name,
        dv.ocr_vatno_country,dv.ocr_is_vatno_verified,dv.ocr_invoice_id_,
        dv.ocr_invoice_time,dv.ocr_invoice_time_due,dv.ocr_fi_type,
        dv.ocr_fi_payment_id_,dv.ocr_is_fi_payment_verified, dv.ocr_fi_creditorno,
        dv.ocr_bank_code,dv.ocr_bank_code_id,dv.ocr_is_bank_code_verified,
        dv.ocr_bank_account,dv.ocr_is_bank_account_verified,dv.ocr_bank_iban,
        dv.ocr_is_bank_iban_verified,dv.ocr_bank_swift,dv.ocr_bank_swift_id,
        dv.ocr_is_bank_swift_verified,dv.ocr_products_pattern,
        dv.ocr_total,dv.ocr_is_total_verified,dv.ocr_vat,dv.ocr_currency
    FROM  `data_voucher` dv
    ORDER BY  dv.time DESC,dv.id DESC
    LIMIT  0,25
```

Rationale:  I turned the JOINs into subqueries, thereby making it obvious that things are 1:1, and letting the Optimizer focus on just the one table (`dv`).  This should allow it to use `INDEX(time, id)` to handle both the `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT`, thereby stopping after 25 rows.

Unfortunately, that still leaves the processing of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.  It must proceed to count the rest of the rows in that index.  So, removing the CALC *may* speed up the query signficantly.  Does the UI *really* need it?

...

Comment: I have removed `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and same problem.. The query hits timeout.. Everthing is 1:1..

Comment: The query is more than 10x slower.. it takes more than 5 minutes and I still haven't managed to complete it because it hits timeout in phpmyadmin

Comment: have updated the question with more info and the results of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Your query with subqueries seems to work.. But I don't get why my query with joins hits timeout..

Comment: @clarkk - I think you have not yet added both of my suggested indexes.

Comment: @clarkk - and need to see datatypes for cv.vatno and dv.ocr_vatno.

Comment: Now it works.. Thanks.. The problem was that in `cache_vatno` I had created (in the update) `UNIQUE INDEX(ref_country_id,vatno)`.. Then you can't search for `vatno` alone.. Thanks.. it works after adding `INDEX(vatno)`

Comment: Consider promoting your UNIQUE key to be the PRIMARY KEY.  Consider swapping the order of those columns (may hurt some other queries, but help this one).  Consider `INDEX(vatno, name)`.  (These suggestions overlap.  Any of these may help.  Doing all won't be as much as the total of each one independently.)

Comment: But shouldn't the PRIMARY KEY not (almost) always be the `id`? When you need to fetch a specific row by `id`

Comment: And another thing I hope you could answer. What is the difference between theese two keys? A: `ADD UNIQUE KEY ref_country_id (ref_country_id,vatno)` and B: `ADD UNIQUE KEY ref_country_id (ref_country_id,vatno) USING BTREE`

Comment: True.  If you are using `id`, then either keep `id` else you would have to change how you reference this table.  (Hence, I said "Consider", not "DO IT!".)

Comment: @clarkk - `USING BTREE` is the default (and the only viable option), so those are equivalent.